# LINQ - Contains with anonymous type

Tags: c#, sql, linq

When using this code (simplified for asking):

```
var rows1 = (from t1 in db.TABLE1
    where (t1.COLUMN_A == 1)
    select new { t1.COLUMN_B, t1.COLUMN_C });

var rows2 = (from t2 in db.TABLE2
    where (rows1.Contains(t2.COLUMN_A))
    select t2;
```

I got the following error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   TSource)' cannot be inferred from the
>   usage. Try specifying the type
>   arguments explicitly.

I need to filter the first result by COLUMN_B, but I don't know how. Is there a way to filter it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to use Contains you must pass an instance of the type in the `IEnumerable<T>`.  This is exceedingly hard with anonymous types.

Instead I would use the `Any` extension method overload which allows you to specify a comparison lambda.  For example

```
var rows2 = (from t2 in db.TABLE2
    where (rows1.Any(x => x.COLUMN_B == t2.COLUMN_A))
    select t2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Any

```
var rows1 = (from t1 in db.TABLE1
    where (t1.COLUMN_A == 1)
    select new { t1.COLUMN_B, t1.COLUMN_C });

var rows2 = (from t2 in db.TABLE2
    where (rows1.Any( r => r.COLUMN_B == t2.COLUMN_A))
    select t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

does this works?

```
var rows1 = (from t1 in db.TABLE1
    where (t1.COLUMN_A == 1)
    select new { t1.COLUMN_B, t1.COLUMN_C }).ToList();

var rows2 = (from t2 in db.TABLE2
    where (rows1.Contains(t2.COLUMN_A))
    select t2;
```